# (default package) in GGTS

Tags: grails, groovy, controller, shiro, ggts

I have a Grails project in GGTS and am authenticating users on an LDAP server with the Shiro security plugin. When I ran `grails quick-start-shiro`, the script created

- `controllers/(default package)AuthController.groovy`
- `domain/(default package)ShiroRole.groovy`
- `domain/(default package)ShiroUser.groovy`

Now, if I create some home page controller, it puts it in `controllers/<project name>/HomeController.groovy` and not `controllers/(default package)/HomeController.groovy`. What I'm wondering is, how can I create a controller and/or domain and have it be in the same (default package)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend using the default package. I have done this in the beginning of my grails "career" and always had problems, for example when importing a class with default package

My suggestion is:

1. delete the domain controller and domain classes generated by the shiro plugin
2. create them again using the --prefix command as shown in the docs (https://grails.org/plugin/shiro)

grails shiro-quick-start --prefix=org.example.

in your case:

grails shiro-quick-start --prefix

Comment: This was kind of a pain, but since my web-app is fairly small currently, I just rebuilt the whole thing with the proper prefix. Trying to do so in the old project gave a lot of errors I couldn't figure out. However, I have it working! Thanks.